# Laravel get latest username

Tags: php, sql, laravel, pdo

I'm trying to get te latest username of my users and show that in stats, but id doesn't work.

I'm using laravel.

My code:

```
$users = DB::table('user')->select('username')->get();
```

I get an error;

> ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)  Array to string conversion (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CubicCMS_new\system\app\views\layouts\master.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CubicCMS_new\system\app\views\layouts\master.blade.php)

But i don't see the array to string conversion?

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're essentially asking Laravel for the usernames of *all* users. What you want is `pluck`, and probably also to sort by id in reverse. Like this:

```
DB::table('user')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->pluck('username');
```

Also, it's a best practice to name the table `users`, because it's one table that consists of many users, not one table that consists of one user. But of course, that's up to you entirely. :)

Edit: Having read the question again, I'm wondering if perhaps you do want all usernames after all. In that case, a standard loop *should* work, i.e.

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    {{ $user->username }}
@endforeach
```

And if it doesn't, please post your code so we can have a closer look!

Comment: Oh, i was looking at pluck but i couldn't find it. Thanks for the quick support! It works awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is completed!

```
DB::table('user')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->pluck('username');
```

Was the solution. Thanks to Joer Hinz